# select count(*) not working with perl DBI

Tags: sql, perl, odbc, dbi

The goal of my code is to return a count of the number of rows in a table based on one specific parameter.

Here is code that works:

```
######### SQL Commands
### Connect to the SQL Database
my $dbh = DBI->connect($data_source, $user, $pass)
    or die "Can't connect to $data_source: $DBI::errstr";

### Prepare the SQL statement and execute
my $sth1 = $dbh->selectrow_array("select count(*) from TableInfo where Type = '2'")
or die "Can't connect to $data_source: $DBI::errstr";

### Disconnect from Database statements are completed.
$dbh->disconnect;
######### end SQL Commands 


print $sth1;
```

This will successfully print a number which is 189 in this instance.
When I try to use the same code but change the "Type = '2'" (which should return a value of 2000) I get the following error:

```
DBD::ODBC::db selectrow_array failed: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Numeric value out of range (SQL-22003) at ./getTotalExpSRP.cgi line 33, <DATA> line 225.
Can't connect to dbi:ODBC:BLTSS_SRP: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Numeric value out of range (SQL-22003) at ./getTotalExpSRP.cgi line 33, <DATA> line 225.
```

I've search everywhere but I cannot find out why this happens.
From the symptom of the issue I would guess that there is a limit to the size of the results returned but I cannot find any supporting evidence of this.

I have run a trace on my Microsoft SQL 2005 server and can confirm that the sql statement is being run properly with no errors.

I've viewed my odbc trace log but unfortunately I cannot derive any useful information when comparing a working example to the failed one.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now we've seen the trace I can explain this. DBD::ODBC calls SQLDescribeCol and is told:

DescribeCol column = 1, name = , namelen = 0, type = unknown(0), precision/column size = 10, scale = 0, nullable = 1
     display size = 11

Then it calls SQLColAttribute and is told the column size is 4. Since the column type was unknown (why the driver did that I'm not sure) DBD::ODBC decides to bind the column as a char(4) and so as soon as the count is > 3 digits it will overflow.

The version of DBI and DBD::ODBC being used here is really old and I suspect the latest versions will cope better with this.

Comment: This was the answer. Once I upgraded my modules I no longer received any errors. Also it may be worth noting that I was not required to use bind_col

Answer (score 2):

`Numeric value out of range` is a type conversion error. Is `TYPE` supposed to be a number of a character/string? If it should be a number, use a number

```
my $sth1 = $dbh->selectrow_array(
    "select count(*) from TableInfo where Type=2")  # Type=2, not Type='2'
```

or use placeholders and let Perl and the database driver worry about type conversions

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select count(*) from TableInfo where Type=?");
$sth->execute(2);
$sth->execute('2');     # same thing
my $st1 = $sth->fetchall_arrayref;
```

Comment: trying this method gives me the same error message. I dont believe it is a problem with the SQL statement. It seems like it cant handle the response from SQL. The only proof I have of this is is that when Type = 2 I get successful data. Only when Type = 1 is when it fails.  The difference in the data is size 189 vs 2000 - hopefully this gives some insight.

Comment: Another price of evidence to prove its likely not the SQL statement is that if I use  

    my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select count(*) from TableInfo where Type=?");
    $sth->execute(1); 
    $sth->finish;

There is no error. Only when I try to manipulate the response after the execute command do I get errors.

Comment: What version of perl DBI have you got? perl -MDBI -le 'print $DBI::VERSION'. If it is a recentish and so is DBD::ODBC set/export DBI_TRACE=DBD=x.log and run it again then post lines from x.log from just before the failure. You may need different quotes in that version code for Windows.

Comment: I am running DBI version 1.52. I ran export DBI_TRACE=DBD=/var/log/DBI.log and then ran the script but there is nothing printed int the DBI.log file. what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Too old a version. set DBI_TRACE=15=x.log and rerun. BTW, what version of DBD::ODBC are you using?

Comment: OMG, that is extremely old - September 2009. The current version is 1.43. Upgrade. Look how many changes and fixes since then at http://search.cpan.org/~mjevans/DBD-ODBC-1.43/Changes

Comment: I copied the log to a temp-share link found here [TempShare](http://temp-share.com/show/HKdPx6Y3A) since it was too large to copy into the comments. Please let me know if you find anything helpful

Comment: The problem is the column type for count(*) was not returned - see "type = unknown(0)" and so DBD::ODBC fell back to a VARCHAR of size 4 returned by SQLColAttribute. As soon as the result is more than 3 digits it will fail. Strictly speaking I think this ODBC driver is broken but I believe if you upgrade your DBI and DBD::ODBC it will work around the problem.

Comment: Just for informations sake I have upgraded DBI to 1.623 and DBD::ODBC to 1.43 and the issue persists. Currently I am researching to see if there is a way to force the type to be something that will work.

Comment: Ok, at least we are on the latest versions. Produce another log from latest DBI and DBD::ODBC but this time use DBI_TRACE=DBD=x.log and post it somewhere for me to examine. I maintain DBD::ODBC and can probably workaround the issue for you. You could try binding the column yourself as an SQL_INTEGER but I'd still like to workaround it automatically. See bind_col in DBI. You don't actually have to bind to a scalar you can just call bind_col(1, undef, {TYPE=>SQL_INTEGER}).

Comment: Unfortunately I am still not able to use the DBI_TRACE=DBD=/var/lot/x.log - when I run my script I get this error: DBI->parse_trace_flags(DBD) ignored unknown trace flags: 'DBD' at /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/DBI.pm line 269 ---- I went ahead and used the other export command to get the log and placed it here: [TempShare](http://temp-share.com/show/YgFHvkPxy)

Comment: Note: in the above attempt I used this code instead `my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select count(*) from SRPInfo");
$sth->execute();
$sth->bind_col(1, undef, {TYPE => SQL_INTEGER});

$sth->fetchrow_array;

$sth->finish;` but in order for this to try I had to remove `use strict` from my code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27509/discussion-between-satarian-and-bohica)

Comment: I'm sat in chat if you want to take this further.